# Building boost cpp via Xcode works, via brew caused incompatibility

Tags: xcode, boost, homebrew

I've had to resort to compiling boost cpp files in my Xcode project because when I used `brew install boost --universal` and linked the static libraries, my software became incompatible with all mac os versions except 10.11 (had a friend tested on 10.9 and 10.8, I'm on 10.11). Is there a setting I am not aware of with brew/boost that causes it to make static libraries specifically for 10.11?

Comment: Might be slightly related: I think there was an issue with `--universal` that would not end up in a universal boost installation if Python has not been installed with `--universal` as well... Not sure it would apply to that specific problem (which to me stems from the MacOS Deployment Target parameter set to a too high version). Might be worth a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/48437#issuecomment-174522431

Brew deployment target is the Mac OS version it is being used on. Therefore, brew is not a viable option to build boost.